# Question on the construction of Poisson processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am currently studying John Kingman's "Poisson processes", and stumbled upon the following passage, where the author introduces the inevitability of the Poisson distribution:

Here, $N(A)$ counts the number of random points being in the set $A$.

> Think of a test set $A_t$, which is in two dimensions a circle of radius $t$ (though it could equally be a square of side $t$). Write
>   \begin{align*}
> p_n(t) &= \mathbb{P}\{ N(A_t) = n \}, \\
> q_n(t) &= \mathbb{P}\{ N(A_t) \le n \}.
> \end{align*}
>   […]
>
> The random variable $N(A_t)$ jumps from $n$ to $n+1$ when its enlarging boundary crosses one of the random points. The probability that this occurs between $t$ and $t+h$ is the probability that there is a point in the ring between $A_t$ and $A_{t+h}$, which we suppose small when $h$ is small. If we ignore the probability of two or more points in this ring, this probability (given the number in $A_t$ is the same as
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{1}
>   \mu(t+h) - \mu(t),
> \end{equation}
>   where
>   $\mu(t) = \mathbb{E}\{N(A_t)\}$.
>
> If this is independent of the number of points in $A_t$, then for small $h$,
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag{2}
> q_n(t) - q_n(t+h) = p_n(t) \{ \mu(t+h)-\mu(t) \}.
> \end{equation}

I fail to see how the last statement $(2)$ is true, i.e. why $q_n(t) - q_n(t+h)$ is the same as 
$$
  p_n(t) \{ \mu(t+h)-\mu(t) \}.
$$

I am grateful for any suggestion and tip.

Comment: What is your approach to an explanation of this (approximate) identity?

Comment: Well I tried to see why the left-hand side is less or equal than the right-hand side, and then why the right-hand side is less or equal than the left-hand side. Unfortunately, I can't seem to establish a relation between those two sides and have no intuition on how I could start

Comment: Sorry but your last comment is remarkably empty of any substance (and could have been written by a bot).

Comment: I thought maybe another way to look at this is to say $q_n(t)-q_n(t+h)$ = $\sum_{i=0}^{n} p_i(t) - \sum_{i=0}^{n} p_i(t+h)$. Then if $h$ is small, one may perhaps assume that $p_i(t) - p_i(t+h)$ can be neglected for, for instance, $i = 0,...,n-1$, so that $q_n(t) - q_n(t+h)$ = $p_n(t) - p_n(t+h)$. It has however gotten quite muddy and I do not see how $\mu(t+h) -\mu(t)$ comes into play